# Where can I find the English text of the 1970's The Law and Administration Arrangements Law?

Tags: israel

According to this text in the Jerusalem Post, it says,

> In **1970**, three years after the Six Day War, Israel passed legislation to deal with various issues that arose in the wake of its takeover of the West Bank. Among many other provisions, the law, known as **The Law and Administration Arrangements Law**, allowed Jews who had lost property in east Jerusalem and the West Bank to reclaim it.

When I look for that law using Google. I can't find it, where is the text for this law?

Answer (score 1):

One source of laws for Israel is [Ruling Palestine: A history of the legally sanctioned Jewish-Israeli seize of land and housing in Palestine](https://www.badil.org/phocadownloadpap/Badil_docs/publications/Ruling%20Palestine.pdf) published by Centre on Housing Rights and Evictions (COHRE) and BADIL Resource Center for Palestinian Residency & Refugee Right. In it, is documented,

> Legal and Administrative Matters (Regulation) Law (Consolidated Version), 5730-1970

According to gov.il,

> Under section 5 of the Legal and Administrative Matters (Regulation) Law [Consolidated Version] 1970, the Guardian General also manages property which was formerly administered by the Jordanian Custodian of Enemy Property. Following the War of Independence, assets of Jews situated in areas of the West Bank outside the jurisdictional boundaries of the State of Israel were vested in the Jordanian Custodian of Enemy Property. In 1967 these assets were vested in the ruling military authorities and in 1970 responsibility for those assets within the jurisdiction of Greater Jerusalem's municipal boundaries was transferred to the Guardian General

> Properties in East Jerusalem that are administered pursuant to section 5 of the Legal and Administrative Matters (Regulation) Law [Consolidated Version] 1970, can be transferred to state property if the Court is satisfied that there is no justification to continue their management by the Guardian General (section 15 (c4)).

Answer (score 1):

The *Hebrew* text is available online from the Knesset, [חוק הסדרי משפט ומינהל [נוסח משולב], התש"ל-1970](https://main.knesset.gov.il/Activity/Legislation/Laws/Pages/LawPrimary.aspx?t=lawlaws&st=lawlawsvalidity&lawitemid=2001137). That page includes a link to the [original 1970 version](https://main.knesset.gov.il/activity/legislation/laws/pages/lawsecondary.aspx?lawitemid=2002248) and some subsequent amendments. There is a [PDF facsimile](https://fs.knesset.gov.il//7/law/7_lsr_311012.PDF) of the official print version.

Obviously you have asked for an English version of the text. In print, the official translation should be found in the series *Laws of the State of Israel* published by the Government Printer since 1948. That is the authoritative source for English-language versions of Israel's legislative texts. You would have to find a library convenient to you that has a copy of the relevant volume. It does not look like there is a free digitised version online.

If physical library sources are not convenient then you might be able to cobble some understanding together from the Hebrew text, a friend who reads Hebrew, and/or a bit of machine translation. Unfortunately, Google Translate doesn't seem to do so well on legal Hebrew: your link to the "Ruling Palestine" report translates section 26 of the 1970 law as

> [f]rom the day of the coming into force of an application of law order, section 2 of the State Property Law, 5711-1951,
> shall apply mutatis mutandis to property situated in the area of application of such order of the state which was in de
> facto occupation of such area or of any of the authorities of such state.

whereas Google thinks it says

> From the date of commencement of the order of application of the law, section 2 of the State Property Law, 1951, will apply, in the changes required according to the matter, on property of the state or of an authority from its authorities which area The applicability of the order was actually occupied by her and the property is in the same area

which is... less fluent.